# How to create multiple POs at once using Acumatica?

Tags: api, acumatica

I found this interface, but it can only create one PO at a time.

API: http://192.168.2.177/AcumaticaERP1/entity/Default/17.200.001/PurchaseOrder

JSON:

`{
    "VendorID": {
        "value": "WELU10"
    },
    "Description": {
        "value": "From Orderock"
    },
    "Details": [{
      "InventoryID": {
        "value": "10J10"
      },
      "OrderQty": {
        "value": 10
      },
      "UnitCost": {
        "value": 24.5
      }
    }, {
      "InventoryID": {
        "value": "10SL"
      },
      "OrderQty": {
        "value": 7
      },
      "UnitCost": {
        "value": 21.5
      }
    }]
}`

Answer (score 1):

Presently there's no built-in API to allow batch creation. You can use import scenarios or implement your own endpoint.